# Jquery Scroll when page loaded

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

What I'm trying to do is very simple, but i can't find any ways to do it (and i've searched!)

I want that, when the page is loaded, the page scroll to an element with a `class=""` in the page.
I've seen that there are a lot of plugins, and i've tried thing like this :

```
     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".class").offset().top
     }, 2000);
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

Comment: what's the difference between this and what i've already tried ? :/

Comment: @Dellwolf the difference is that he's calling the `animate scrollTop` when the document is ready. If the answer he gave helped you to solve your question, please mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: i already know that i have to mark if it helped, Thanks Pedro. anyway, yes the fiddle works Palash, but in my code, i did call the animate after the document is ready, but it still doesn't work. Ok, the thing is that i have a lot of functions, the problem must be coming from my code. I'll try to find where it comes from. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at scrollTo(). It's a plugin and it works nicely, lets you set scrolls to any element, percent of page, anchors. Also can setup multiple scrolls, scrolls inside child elements fairly easily.

Link: http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/